# Compile multiple .c files in xcode - head first

Tags: c

My question is regarding an exercise of the book which I am using for learning C; head first. In the exercise we are learning to share functions between certain .c files. I am working in Xcode 8.2.1 and wanted to know whether Xcode can compile this exercise for me. I've got it to work correctly with the terminal, but I was wondering whether Xcode allows this compilation and that I've just got something wrong in my properties or something.

The program is a simple XOR-encryption program.

This are the files:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "encrypt.h"

int main()
{
    char msg[80];
    printf("Type your message to be encrypted:\n");
    while (fgets(msg, 80, stdin)) {
        encrypt(msg);
        printf("The encrypted message is like this: %s\n", msg);
        encrypt(msg);
        printf("The encrypted message is decrypted as: %s\n",msg);
        printf("Type your message to be encrypted:\n");
    }
}
```

encrypt.h:

```
#ifndef ENCRYPT_H_ 
#define ENCRYPT_H_

void encrypt(char *message);

#endif
```

encrypt.c:

```
#include "encrypt.h"

void encrypt(char *message)
{
    while (*message) {
        *message = *message ^ 31;
        message++;
    }
}
```

Now I get an error in the main.c file saying that there is a conflicting type for the function encrypt. This says to me that it sees encrypt as an int-valued function (by default). I think the problem is that the program does not see the encrypt function correctly, however I've given it acces to the correct header file with the correct declaration etc. So that makes me think there is some compiler problem.

**Edit:** The error messages are:

```
Semantic Issue Group: 
PATH/message_hider/encrypt.h:9:6: Conflicting types for 'encrypt'
PATH/message_hider/main.c:17:9: Implicit declaration of function 'encrypt' is invalid in C99
```

Comment: Did you add additional files to that project (File -> New File -> Header File). ?

Comment: The way I added the encrypt.c and encrypt.h files is by adding a file to the project (right-click on main.c -> new file -> add .c file (include the header)) and give the names.

Comment: What is the **exact, complete** error message you get?

Comment: Please give the full exact error message, including (if relevant) the line where error is detected.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by complete error. The IDE only says ' build failed' and highlights certain parts of code with the error message above. Next to the code windows it says: Semantic Issue Group: PATH/message_hider/encrypt.h:9:6: Conflicting types for 'encrypt' and PATH/message_hider/main.c:17:9: Implicit declaration of function 'encrypt' is invalid in C99

Comment: PSJ To start with, add `#ifndef ENCRYPT_H_` and `#define ENCRYPT_H_` to the beginning of your .h file and end your .h file with `#endif`.

Comment: Ok, I've done that (edited it above so that you can see whether its correct). It still gives the same error.

Comment: @PJS Your code looks correct, and there is no reason why Xcode shouldn't be able to compile this for you.  What if you temporarily remove your `#include "encrypt.h"` from main.c and replace it with `void encrypt(char *message);`?  I'm wondering if there might be some prior definition of function `encrypt()` that the compiler is seeing, though I can't imagine where.

Comment: @PJS The error referencing line 9 of encrypt.h is confusing because the encrypt.h that you posted seems to have only 6 lines.  Can you include the _full_ encrypt.h, or re-build and update the error message?  When the compiler processes encrypt.h, it sounds like it already has an encrypt() function defined, so it ignores your new prototype, and consequently doesn't agree with your invocation of `encrypt(msg);`.  Try renaming your function to `pjs_encrypt()` to see what that does.